ParticleUniforms to MDLMesh
I am working on 3D iOS Scanner with Lidar and I try to extract pointcloud data in particle uniforms to 3D object and export it as OBJ. But I don't know how. Any way to convert particle uniforms to MDLMesh ?
Here is my code:
  func saveOBJFormat() {
        
        let allocator = MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: device)
        let asset = MDLAsset(bufferAllocator: allocator)
        let vertexDescriptor = MDLVertexDescriptor()
        vertexDescriptor.attributes[0] = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributePosition, format: .float3, offset: 0, bufferIndex: 0)
        vertexDescriptor.attributes[1] = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeColor, format: .float3, offset: MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.stride, bufferIndex: 0)
        vertexDescriptor.layouts[0] = MDLVertexBufferLayout(stride: MemoryLayout<ParticleUniforms>.stride)
            
        
        for i in 0..<currentPointCount {
            let point = particlesBuffer[i]
            let colors = point.color
            let position = point.position
            print(point, "point")
        }
        
        //  I blank in here
                
        let pic = cvPixelBuffer2UIImage(pixelBuffer: sampleFrame.capturedImage)
        print(pic, "picture")
        
        let asset = MDLAsset()
        asset.add(mdlMesh)
        
        let fileExtension = "obj"
        guard MDLAsset.canExportFileExtension(fileExtension) else {
            fatalError("Cant export a .\(fileExtension) format")
        }

        do {
            let url = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(currentFolder, isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("\(getTimeStr()).obj")
            try asset.export(to: url)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

Thank you
How to convert particle uniforms to MDLMesh ?
